# How do I get my function to print my code?

Tags: python

So I'm making a program that rolls dice until it gets snake eyes. The problem is that whenever I run my code it doesn't print anything. And when it ran before it was an infinite loop. I'll put my code below. I know there's definitely an easier way to do this but I just want it to be able to function first.

```
def snakeEyes():
#Simulate dice
#Variables to store integers
  diceCount = 0
  dice1 = 3
  dice2 = 4
  diceSum = dice1 + dice2

  while(diceSum != 2):
    dice1 = random.randint(1,6)
    dice2 = random.randint(1,6)
    diceCount = diceCount + 1

# if both 1's - snake eyes
    if(dice1 + dice2 == 2):
      combo_name = "snake eyes"
  # if both 6's - boxcars
    elif(dice1 + dice2 == 12):
      combo_name = "boxcars"
  #if 7 --> natural
    elif(diceSum == 7):
      combo_name = "natural"
  #if sum % 2 == 0 -- we got an even
    # if dice values are same -- "hard"
    # else - easy
    # turn the sum number into text number
    elif(diceSum % 2 == 0):
      if(dice1 == dice2):
        combo_name = "hard " + str(diceSum)
      else:
        combo_name = "easy " + str(diceSum)
  # else - have an odd number
  # figure out which odd name we are using
    else:
      if(diceSum == 3):
        combo_name = "ace deuce"
      elif(diceSum == 5):
        combo_name = "fever five"
      elif(diceSum == 9):
        combo_name = "nina"
      elif(diceSum == 11):
        combo_name = "yo-leven"

  #Print line with dice values and names
      print ("Dice1: " + str(dice1)+ "  Dice 2: " + str(dice2)+ "   " + combo_name)

  print("The dice rolled " + str(diceCount) + " times before it got snake eyes.")


print(snakeEyes())
```

Comment: indent your `print` line back

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`diceSum` was declared before the `while` loop, and is never reassigned again, so its value is always `7`. In the loop you should add the line: `diceSum = dice1 + dice2`

EDIT: the `diceCount` is because of this
[image]

The `print` is in the `else` condition.

Comment: Add more note: the function `snakeEyes` does not return anything, so `print(snakeEyes())` will print `None`. You can just use `snakeEyes()` because in the function there is already the `print` line.

Comment: It worked but now there's a whole new problem lol. The count function isn't accurate.

Comment: What's the problem with `diceCount`?

Comment: It doesn't show the correct number of times before it gets snake eyes. For example, the code could run 6 times but it would say it took 15 tries before it got snake eyes.

Comment: Edited my answer so you can see the indentation error.

Answer (score 2):

Your function already prints, so while calling the functions don't use `print()` instead try like this: `snakeEyes()`

Answer (score 2):

The main problem is here is that you never reassign value to diceSum in the while loop, and thus diceSum is forever 7.

```
import random


def snakeEyes():
    # Simulate dice
    # Variables to store integers
    diceCount = 0
    diceSum = 0
    while(diceSum != 2):
        dice1 = random.randint(1, 6)
        dice2 = random.randint(1, 6)
        diceSum = dice1 + dice2
        diceCount = diceCount + 1

        # if both 1's - snake eyes
        if diceSum == 2:
            combo_name = "snake eyes"
        # if both 6's - boxcars
        elif diceSum == 12:
            combo_name = "boxcars"
        # if 7 --> natural
        elif diceSum == 7:
            combo_name = "natural"
        # if sum % 2 == 0 -- we got an even
        # if dice values are same -- "hard"
        # else - easy
        # turn the sum number into text number
        elif diceSum % 2 == 0:
            if dice1 == dice2:
                combo_name = "hard " + str(diceSum)
            else:
                combo_name = "easy " + str(diceSum)
        # else - have an odd number
        # figure out which odd name we are using
        else:
            if diceSum == 3:
                combo_name = "ace deuce"
            elif diceSum == 5:
                combo_name = "fever five"
            elif diceSum == 9:
                combo_name = "nina"
            elif diceSum == 11:
                combo_name = "yo-leven"

        # Print line with dice values and names
        print("Dice1: " + str(dice1) + "  Dice 2: " + str(dice2) + "   " + combo_name)

    print("The dice rolled " + str(diceCount) + " times before it got snake eyes.")


snakeEyes()
```